# Interpretation a raw data from touch screen controller(ADS7843) on stm32

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

guys!

I'm working on embedded project and I've never faced such problem before. The problem I will explain below.

My environment:

- custom board with STM32F429ZI controller;
- ER TFT024-3 display (ili 9341), 240x320;
- touch screen controller ADS7843.

Display and touch screen controller are connected via SPI protocol and used the same port. And I would like to mention that I use software SPI.

The problem is that I can not interpret data from touch screen controller to the real screen coordinates.

Here is an example of the results:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JppOu.png)

```
#define  UB_TOUCH_CMD_CH3  0x900000   // CH=X+, Mode=12bit, DiffEnded, PwrDown
#define  UB_TOUCH_CMD_CH4  0xD00000   // CH=Y+, Mode=12bit, DiffEnded, PwrDown

void BSP_TS_GetState(TS_StateTypeDef* TsState)
{
  static uint32_t _x = 0, _y = 0;
  uint16_t xDiff, yDiff , x , y, xr, yr;

  TsState->TouchDetected = TsDrv->DetectTouch();

  if(TsState->TouchDetected)
  {
    TsDrv->GetXY(&x, &y);

    // Here is convertation from raw data to display coordinates.
    // ....

    /* Update the X position */
    TsState->X = x;

    /* Update the Y position */
    TsState->Y = y; 
  }
}
```

TsDrv->GetXY calls method ads7843_TS_GetXY

```
void ads7843_TS_GetXY(uint16_t *X, uint16_t *Y)
{
    // ...
    *X = P_Touch_Frame(UB_TOUCH_CMD_CH3 );
    *Y = P_Touch_Frame(UB_TOUCH_CMD_CH4 );
}

uint16_t P_Touch_Frame(uint32_t frame) 
{
    uint16_t n;
    uint32_t maske_out = 0x800000; 
    uint16_t maske_in = 0x800;    
    uint16_t data_in = 0x00;

    TS_CS_LOW();

    for (n = 0; n<24; n++) {
        if ((frame & maske_out) == 0) {
            LCD_SPI_MOSI_LOW();
        }
        else {
            LCD_SPI_MOSI_HIGH();
        }
        LCD_SPI_SCK_HIGH();
        if ((n >= 8) && (n <= 20)) {
            if (LCD_SPI_MISO_GET() != 0) {
                data_in |= maske_in;
            }
            maske_in = (maske_in >> 1);
        }
        LCD_SPI_SCK_LOW();
        maske_out = (maske_out >> 1);
    }  
    TS_CS_HIGH();
    return(data_in);
}
```

I'm looking for existing working driver for this touch screen controller or could you please give me an advice what I'm doing wrong. How should I interpret data correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The ADS7843 is a very simple device. It doesn't work in screen coordinates, it just gives you two numbers that are linearly proportional to the screen coordinates. To convert to screen coordinates, you need to find that linear function (ie. ScreenX = RawX * CoeffX + OffsetX, and likewise for the Y coordinate). Get measurements for two opposite corners and work it out.

Depending on the manufacturing process of your hardware, the linear functions might differ between different units. Thus, you might want to have a calibration function in your firmware.

Also, I found [this resource](http://tstonramp.com/~pddwebacc/ics_app%20notes/burr-brown/ads7843%20app%20notes.pdf) very helpful when programming the ADS7843.